# If we could dig up earth's core (inner, outer), would it expand/ density decrease under room pressure/ vaccuum?

Tags: earth

This is for science fiction writing purposes. The earth's core is super dense compared to surface materials, partially due to the crazy pressure there. I wonder if we could engineer the whole earth, and dig it up, would it occupy more space for the same mass?

Comment: What do you think that "super dense" means in this context? The STP density of iron is around $8\,\mathrm{g/cm^3}$ and google tells me that the core is around $13\,\mathrm{g/cm^3}$ which is less than a factor of two...

Comment: Just wondering if the atomic/ molecular structure of it would expand. 13 is still bigger than 8. Clearly it's nowhere near white dwarf material.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it would occupy more space for the same mass, but the density is only about 4 times that nearer the surface so don't expect a "super crazy" increase.

On the other hand, you may even get a phase transition to liquid for a while (which would also make for some interesting magneto-hydrodynamic effects) if the pressure gets relieved faster than it cools.